# Styling a Google Maps v3 Polyline with Dashes or Dots?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, styling, polyline

I'd like to take a Google Map v3-based map with some custom polylines, and make some of those lines dotted or dashed. I can't seem to find any way of doing this. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Could you please accept the other answer as solution as it is the right one?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This feature has been added to Polyline options, and it's called [**Symbols on Polylines**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols)

Creating a dashed line looks like this ([**demo**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-dashed)):

```
var lineCoordinates = [
  new google.maps.LatLng(22.291, 153.027),
  new google.maps.LatLng(18.291, 153.027)
];

var lineSymbol = {
  path: 'M 0,-1 0,1',
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  scale: 4
};

var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
  path: lineCoordinates,
  strokeOpacity: 0,
  icons: [{
    icon: lineSymbol,
    offset: '0',
    repeat: '20px'
  }],
  map: map
});
```

Dash length is controlled by `path`'s +/-1, and spacing is controlled by `repeat`. It's a bit verbose, but very flexible.

Besides dashes, the new feature includes predefined paths for a circle, arrowheads, and the docs even include an animation demo :)

Comment: When drawing Polygon above code works. But once I complete drawing of the polygon, dashed symbols disappear.