# Drawing dotted line on google maps v2 instead of solid

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Instead of having a polygon with a solid line surrounding it I want to create one with a dotted line, is this possible?

I know you could do this when you override the `onDraw` method of the overlay in `v1` but the `Overlay` class does not exist anymore so how else can I achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6098947/2110460 currently says no

Comment: @Rafe thats the javascript API not android

Comment: I am guessing https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols would not help either then? It seems that first link was a little out dated.

Answer (score 3):

It's currently not possible, but you may upvote this enhancement here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4633

**UPDATE**

Recently, Google implemented this feature for polylines and polygons in Google Maps Android API v2 and marked issue 4633 as Fixed.

See information about stroke patterns in the [Shapes Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#stroke_pattern). See an [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/polygon-tutorial#add_custom_styling_to_your_polygon) in the Polylines and Polygons tutorial.

You can also read the corresponding blog post here:

https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/02/styling-and-custom-data-for-polylines.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, take a look on the API
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline

it is not yet possible with v2, but on v3 javascript API, it already is, look here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#PolylineSymbols

But it seems that it's possible to use this v3 javascript API in an android app, look here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/android_v3

Maybe, this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Find a LatLng at a distance of radius units from center LatLng on Map 
now convert both these LatLngs to screenCoordinates

Use the formula used to construct a cirle x = R*sin(theta) , y = R*cos(theta)

you divide the circle into N segments and then draw polylines(drawn on map) on the circumference of the circle converting the screen coordinates to LatLngs

more the number of N more it looks like a circle , I have used N = 120 according the zoom level ,I am using 13.

```
private void addDottedCircle(double radius) {//radius is in kms

    clearDottedCircle();


    LatLng center,start,end;
    Point screenPosCenter,screenPosStart,screenPosEnd;
    Projection p = mMap.getProjection();

    center = searchCenterMarker.getPosition();
    start = new LatLng(center.latitude + radius/110.54,center.longitude);
    // radius/110.54 gives the latitudinal delta we should increase so that we have a latitude at radius distance
    // 1 degree latitude is approximately 110.54 kms , so the above equation gives you a rough estimate of latitude at a distance of radius distance 


    screenPosCenter = p.toScreenLocation(center);
    screenPosStart = p.toScreenLocation(start);

    double R = screenPosCenter.y - screenPosStart.y;
    int N = 120;//N is the number of parts we are dividing the circle
    double T = 2*Math.PI/N;
    double theta = T;

    screenPosEnd = new Point();
    screenPosEnd.x = (int)(screenPosCenter.x-R*Math.sin(theta));
    screenPosEnd.y = (int) (screenPosCenter.y-R*Math.cos(theta));
    end = p.fromScreenLocation(screenPosEnd);

    for(int i =0;i<N;i++){
        theta+=T;
        if(i%2 == 0){
            //dottedCircle is a hashmap to keep reference to all the polylines added to map
            dottedCircle.add(mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(start,end).width(5).color(Color.BLACK)));

            screenPosStart.x = (int) (screenPosCenter.x-R*Math.sin(theta));
            screenPosStart.y = (int) (screenPosCenter.y-R*Math.cos(theta));
            start = p.fromScreenLocation(screenPosStart);
        }
        else{
            screenPosEnd.x = (int)(screenPosCenter.x-R*Math.sin(theta));
            screenPosEnd.y = (int) (screenPosCenter.y-R*Math.cos(theta));
            end = p.fromScreenLocation(screenPosEnd);
        }

    }

}
```

[image: Image after drawing the dotted circle]

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer have a look at this :

[How to draw dashed polyline with android google map sdk v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721008/how-to-draw-dashed-polyline-with-android-google-map-sdk-v2)