# How to stylize a circle?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

It's possible to stylize polylines with dashes or dots by using icon as described in [Styling a Google Maps v3 Polyline with Dashes or Dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098947/styling-a-google-maps-v3-polyline-with-dashes-or-dots).

But I didn't find how to stylize circles.
Any suggestions, reference please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, draw a circle with a google.maps.Polyline and stylize the polyline:

```
  var donut = new google.maps.Polyline({
                 path: drawCircle(new google.maps.LatLng(-33.9,151.2), 100, 1),
                 strokeOpacity: 0,
                 icons: [{
                   icon: lineSymbol,
                   offset: '0',
                   repeat: '20px'
                 }],
                 strokeWeight: 2,
                 fillColor: "#FF0000",
                 fillOpacity: 0.35
     });
     donut.setMap(map);
```

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_circle_dashed.html)