# How to show map marker in Google Maps API using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to show map marker in Google Maps API using JavaScript?

How to search specific area with display around location? How to show with dotted lines?

Comment: thanks for Khaliov ..  i follow the link  http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/. .but unable to display specific area location search in textbox  i want to show with polygon lines in surround a city.  ex:https://www.google.co.in/maps?hl=en  plese help me  lets example i search Hyderabad city i want to display sorround hyderabad location           TIA

Answer (score 1):

I'm not gonna do the whole job for you, but please have a look at [gmap3](http://gmap3.net/). A jQuery plugin that lets you handle Google Maps in a very easy way.

Include the source file and then just to get started, create a div:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Then, in jQuery, run:

```
$("#map").gmap3();
```

This should generate a Google Map with no specific coordinates. If you want to get more complex, you can read all about that at http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/, but here's an example.

```
$('#map').gmap3({
 marker:{
    latLng:[29.132318972825445,81.32052349999992]
 }
});
```

This puts out a pin at a certain coordinate. They have a clear documentation, so just head over there and follow their instructions. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for Gustaf .. i follow the link gmap3.net/en/catalog. .but unable to display specific area location search in textbox i want to show with polygon lines in surround a city. ex:google.co.in/maps?hl=en plese help me lets example i search Hyderabad city i want to display sorround hyderabad location TIA

Comment: @RaviGuntreddi Something like this? http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/circle-36

Comment: Thanks for Gustaf .. i want to show with poly line in surround a city of search a specific location region area. can you please find below link for your reference. https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Madhapur,+Hyderabad,+Telangana/@17.448437,78.3934532,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x3bcb9158f201b205:0x11bbe7be7792411b?hl=en TIA

Comment: Embed it then? `<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d30449.952696643584!2d78.39293826586915!3d17.448027642656818!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3bcb9158f201b205%3A0x11bbe7be7792411b!2sMadhapur%2C+Hyderabad%2C+Telangana!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1435218536078" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>` @RaviGuntreddi

Comment: Gustaf, Actually i have a requirement to draw like above example which i have provided. But how to integrate in our code dynamically with location or lat and longs? Can you please also check another ref site. https://housing.com/in/rent/search?f=eyJsb2N0IjoicG9seSIsInBvbHkiOnsiaWQiOiIxZmNmOGViZDUzYzZjN2QzMWE1YiIsImJ1ZmZlciI6ZmFsc2V9fQ%3D%3D

Comment: @RaviGuntreddi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098947/styling-a-google-maps-v3-polyline-with-dashes-or-dots Perhaps?